# Привязка HashSet к Input элементу используя thymeleaf, для дальнейшего POST запроса и обработки на стороне контроллера

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, thymeleaf

Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно привязать коллекцию HashSet

Имеется класс App, который содержит Set, которая в последующем создаётся как new HashSet(). В контроллере имеется описание GET метода, в качестве параметра модели я передаю во View вновь созданный экземпляр App, с уже проинициализированным HashSet , который имеет 1 элемент

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/appNew", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView appNew(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    App app = CreateNewApp();
    modelAndView.addObject("app", app);
    modelAndView.setViewName("admin/appEdit");
    return modelAndView;
}

 private App CreateNewApp() throws IOException {
    Version version = new Version();
    version.setComment("AppVersion");
    version.setNumber(0);
    version.setLicense_value(0);
    App app = new App();
    app.setName("Новое приложение");
    app.setAutor("Автор");
    app.setVersions(new HashSet<Version>());
    app.getVersions().add(version);
    return app;
}
```

на стороне View , я делаю итерацию по HashSet

```
<form th:object="${app}" th:action="@{appNew}" method="POST" class="form-signin">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"  th:placeholder="Name" class="form-control" /> <br/>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{autor}"  th:placeholder="Autor" class="form-control" /> <br/>
        <input type="number" th:field="*{active}"  th:placeholder="Active" class="form-control" /> <br/>
          <div  th:object="${app}" class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <div th:each="ver, step :${app.versions}">
              <div th:object="${ver}">
                <input th:field="*{comment}" th:value="${ver.getComment()}" class="card-text"></input>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="Submit" value="create" type="Submit" th:text="Create"></button>
      </form>
```

Значения коллекции корректно заполняются в th:value и отображаются, но при попытке привязки каждого  через th:field для последующего POST запроса возникает ошибка

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'ver' available as request attribute
```

если убрать th:field="*{comment}", то будет выведен список всего HashSet , но данные не уйдут в контроллер обрабатывающий POST запрос т.к. будет отсутствовать привязка

Comment: Когда возникает такое исключение?